# Загрузка фото через инпут

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, vue.js

нужно реализовать загрузку фотографий через текстовый инпут, т.е пользователь вставляет ссылку на картинку в инпут, нажимает добавить и и у него отображается превью добавленного фото.
Подскажите как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: К чему такое обилие меток?

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('button')
   .addEventListener('click', function() {
    const file = document.querySelector('input').files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const img = document.createElement('img');

    reader.onloadend = function () {
       img.src = reader.result;
     }
     if (file) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      document.body.appendChild(img);
     }
   })
```

```html
<input type="file">
<button>Загрузить</button><br>
```